# Using PUT method on Supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, supertest, http-put

How do I use a PUT method with SuperTest? All I get is "404 Not found" as response.

The request handler:

```
router.put('/', function (req, res) {
    res.type('json');

    FooResource(req.body, function () {
        res.send("{}");
    });
});
```

The test suite:

```
describe("PUT /foo/fii", function () {

    it("Respond with 200", function (done) {

        request(app)
            .put('/')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect(200, done);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added:

```
    it("Respond with 200", function (done) {

        request(app)
            .put('/')
            .send("{}")
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                done();
            })

    });
```

And now it works(?)

Comment: it should be `done(err)` or `.end(done)`. Otherwise it won't validate the statusCode

Answer (score 1):

Let me share here an example, using promises, which doesn't require `done()`:

```
describe('PUT: update task (id:5)', function() {
    test('It should return response 200.', function() {
        return request(app)
            .put('/api/v1.0/tasks/5')
            .send({title:'Code Refactor API',user:'ivanleoncz'})
            .expect(200);
    });
});
```

For more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest